# Can I deploy Rational Publishing Engine Data Services on IIS?

Tags: ibm-rational

I shall like to use Rational Publishing Engine for generating documentations for Rational RequisitePro. As such I shall have to deploy RPE Data Services.

Can I deploy data services on IIS? Is Apache/WAS mandatory for the Data Services?

I am eagerly waiting for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RPE Data Services are not supported on IIS.